# C# why does this reload method block the UI for a visible second

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a function that makes a call to an API, and then binds the data to the view (along with a lot of local calculations in between.)

In short, this method looks like this:

```
        private async Task LoadMoreAds()
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {

                await ...random api then
                ... do something with the results then 
                ... bind the views 

            });
        }
```

This method is called from UI event handler:

```
     private async void listview_allAds_FlowItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
{
            TinyAd current = e.Item as TinyAd;
             if (current == contentOfListView[contentOfListView.Count - 2])
                {
                    if (!isCurrentlyLoading)
                        await LoadMoreAds();     
                 }        
            }
    
}
```

I think I am doing all my async and awaits correctly.

But still i am seeing a slight hang on UI reload when the user scrolls fast-
Also the framerate is not at 60, rather at avg of 30.

Is there something I can optimize?

Comment: why you run an async task inside the task on the `LoadMoreAds` task? You should add [ConfigureAwait](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) to your non UI task because of [this](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f). Also you should [avoid async voids](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/) and make use of the [Xamarin Essentials Main Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread) feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions .

1. Stop using a Task inside another Task, just remove the inner `Task.Run` .
2. Do not `await` **LoadMoreAds**  outside , use `await` inside `LoadMoreAds` method.
3. Do the **binding** stuff in xaml not inside `LoadMoreAds` method , just request data and modify the binding source(don't involve view manipulation otherwise you need to update it on main thread ).

Refer to the sample here : https://montemagno.com/load-more-items-at-end-of-listview-in/.